How to make square into triangle by matrix3d?
How can I turn a square into a triangle with a matrix3d transformation?
Expected:
enter image description here
For example, a trapezoid obtained from a square usign matrix3d:


.trapezoid {
  width: 80px; 
  height: 80px; 
  background-color: black;
  transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
<div class="trapezoid"></div>



I have tried using clip-path, but can I do it without it?

Do you feel you could look at a square a certain way and see a triangle ? How would it work if it was an image (would all the pixels find a place in your triangle and in wich way) ? Matrix3D is just a 'camera angle' thing. If you want to 'lose' some part of your square clip is one way to do, but transform will impact performance by doing 3D computations where maybe it is not what you really want.

What was wrong with your use of clip-path(), is this question to resolve a functional necessity or purely curiosity? I ask because many - including myself - will look at this question and just advise you to use clip-path, because it's probably the easiest way to achieve the stated requirement. As Neil already implied, it may not be possible to orient a square in such a way that it looks like a right-angled - or any other - triangle.

Not the best idea but doable if you consider some perspective and adjust the transform origin as well. No need to play with matrix3d()
I didn't do any calculation, I manually adjusted the value until I get close to the shape.


.trapezoid {
  width: 80px; 
  height: 80px; 
  background-color: black;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: perspective(1px) scaleY(45) rotateX(-30deg);
}
<div class="trapezoid"></div>



If you want the matrix, you can get it from the computed tab


.trapezoid {
  width: 80px; 
  height: 80px; 
  background-color: black;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38.9711, -0.5, 0.5, 0, 22.5, 0.866025, -0.866025, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
<div class="trapezoid"></div>



